# How to list files and directories with directories first

Tags: command-line, shell-script, ls

I have two questions. First, which command lists files and directories, but lists directories first?

Second question: I want to copy a list of files into a single directory, but make the target directory the first filename in the command.

Comment: `ls` has a `--group-directories-first` switch.

Comment: `-t` is a possibly a GNU-only option to `cp` that takes an explicit target directory and hence can go anywhere in the command line, including the beginning.

Comment: even shorter in my current bash with version 5.1.16: `ls --g`

Answer (score 69):

## Got GNU?

The gnu version of `ls` has `--group-directories-first`. And `cp` has `-t`.

## No GNU?

On systems that don't have gnu's `ls`, your best bet is two successive calls to `find` with `-maxdepth n`/`-mindepth n` and `-type t` with the appropriate options.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \! -type d
```

For copying files, with the target first, you would have to write a script that saves the first argument, then uses `shift`, and appends the argument to the end.

```
#!/bin/sh
target="$1"
shift
cp -r -- "$@" "$target"
```

## Watch Out!

If you were planning on using these together - that is, collecting the list from `find` or `ls` (possibly by using `xargs`) and passing it to `cp` (or a `cp` wrapper), you should be aware of what [dangers lie in parsing lists of files](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (basically, filenames can contain characters like newlines that can mess up your script). Specifically, look into `find`'s `-exec` and `-print0` options and `xargs`'s `-0` option.

## An alternative tool for efficiently copying directory trees.

You might want to look into using [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) instead; it has lots of functionality that might make your job easier.

Comment: This is great. More generally, is there any way of knowing if I have the GNU version? (other than trying the option `--group-directories-first`).

Comment: You can run `ls --version` to find out which one you have.

Comment: i wish i could upvote this twice for your making awareness of troublesome newlines etc in filenames. programmers shouldn't assume alll the user's filenames are sane! you never know when that curveball will appear :) thanks

Answer (score 22):

works for **bash** and **zsh**

just add alias in ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc

```
# Colorize the ls output ##
alias ls='LC_COLLATE=C ls -h --group-directories-first --color=auto'
```

Also if you have ZSH, you can use ["k"](https://github.com/supercrabtree/k) utility

```
k -h --group-directories-first
```

[image]

just install it with antigen, by putting the following into ~/.zshrc

```
antigen bundle reduxionist/k --branch=add-sort-options
```

Comment: nice answer to offer the alias.

Comment: Maybe better with `ls -alh`.

Answer (score 12):

Listing directories first for a non-GNU `ls`:

`ls -l | sort`

Note, this will list all the bunch of other weird stuff like symlinks, sockets and pipes as well (appropriately grouped, of course), but considering that stuff is quite rare that shouldn't be a problem. Otherwise the filter would be `ls -l | grep '^(-|d)' | sort`

Comment: +1 clever and shorter than the accepted answer. _Except_ that it really should be `sort -r`.

Comment: ls -l | sort didn't work for me on a Mac.  It groups the directories first but it didn't sort them nor did it sort the filenames that followed.

Comment: also note: using the  ` | sort` will remove your color as it is now text.

Answer (score 3):

For non-GNU like **MacOS**, awk can filter all the other fields:

```
ls -l | sort -r | awk 'NF==9 { if ($1~/^d/) { print $9 "/" } else { print $9 } }'
```

- NF==9: the output of `ls -l` must contains 9 fields
- if line starts with 'd', prints an extra '/'
- otherwise just the file name

The output looks like `ls -1` but with directories put first:

```
node_modules/
src/
e2e/
angular.json
tslint.json
package.json
README.md
```

According to "The Long Format" of ls man page, when other file types get involved, the output order should be:

```
   s     Socket link.
   p     FIFO.
   l     Symbolic link.
   d     Directory.
   c     Character special file.
   b     Block special file.
   -     Regular file.
```

A handy bash function (put it in your .bash_profile or .bashrc):

```
function l1() {
  ls -l $* | sort -r | awk 'NF==9 { if ($1~/^d/) { print $9 "/" } else { print $9 } }'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My version with colorized folder and file names, based on @clarkttfu's solution with a bunch of improvements. Tested on MacOS.

```
ls -lh | sort -r | awk 'NF==9 { if ($1~/^d/) { printf $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4 "/" $5 "/" $6 " " $7 "/" $8 " " "\033[1;34m" $9 "\033[0m" "\n" } else { printf $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4 "/" $5 "/" $6 " " $7 "/" $8 " " "\033[1;32m" $9 "\033[0m" "\n" } }' | column -t -s"/"
```

or create an alias:

```
alias ll='ls -lh | sort -r | awk '\''NF==9 { if ($1~/^d/) { printf $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4 "/" $5 "/" $6 " " $7 "/" $8 " " "\033[1;34m" $9 "\033[0m" "\n" } else { printf $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4 "/" $5 "/" $6 " " $7 "/" $8 " " "\033[1;32m" $9 "\033[0m" "\n" } }'\'' | column -t -s"/"'
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. do you know how to improve it so each of two groups would be also sorted case-insensitive way?

Answer (score 0):

For `zsh`'s completion listings, you can set the `list-dirs-first` style to `true` for directories to be shown first. In your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-dirs-first true
```

(here applied to *all* completion widgets that support it and for all commands; you can restrict that if you like, see the `zstyle` documentation for details)

If you've not done so already, make sure to run `compinstall` as well to get completion lists in colour, with descriptions, etc and all the other goodies.

---

To list the files (`print`ed `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn), with those of type directory first:

```
print -rC1 -- *(N/) *(N^/)
```

Including hidden ones:

```
print -rC1 -- *(ND/) *(ND^/)
```

Considering symlinks to directories as directories:

```
print -rC1 -- *(ND-/) *(ND^-/)
```

You could also define a glob qualifier sorting function:

```
dirsfirst() {
  [[ -d $REPLY ]]
  REPLY=$?$REPLY
}
```

An then use as:

```
print -rC1 -- *(o+dirsfirs)
```

(in that case, symlinks to dirs are also considered as dirs).